# Granularity in a Normal Quantile Plot

Tags: normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics, qq-plot

I'm having some trouble understanding the concept of granularity so I'd like to have some clarity in this regard. After producing a normal Q-Q plot of some data (seen below), a question has asked me to suggest what could be the cause of the granularity of the plot.

[image: The plot in question.]

After a lot of time researching, the only information I found was that the cause was due to the "discreteness" of the data, which makes sense but my gut tells me that there is more to this than simply the data is "discrete". Furthermore, if the data is discrete, then how can it be normally distributed? I think I can explain this through the use of the fact that the majority of the data matches well with the Q-Q line, ignoring the outliers at the tails of the plot. (If I am wrong here could you explain why?)

Basically, my question is whether the granularity of the plot is due only to the discrete nature of the data that I used and if not, could you explain why?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The opinion of your gut is not much help to us as a justification. Can you give a better reason to think it's not just the discreteness of the data? What would distinguish the appearance you'd get with just discrete data from what you see here?

Comment: It's not really a justification, it's more like explaining that it is due to the discreteness of the data seems too simple.

Comment: The only thing that can cause "granularity" is discreteness.  With perfectly continuous measurements, there can be no repeats, and therefore no granularity.